# Does this community have an official stance on entire paragraphs of an answer devoted to berating the asker?

Tags: discussion, answers

The answerer to a certain question had this to say when the questioner edited his question to make some clarifications;

> The above was written in response to the original question, which made
>   no mention of this mouse not being USB. Since pretty much all new mice
>   have been USB for a decade or more, it was reasonable to answer in
>   that context. When you ask about something unusual, it's your
>   responsibility to make that clear.

Above this paragraph was a good answer for USB mice - and below it a good answer for non USB. This whole paragraph doesn't add any value to the question and exists only to berate the asker.

So I edited it out, and the edit got accepted. He just reverted the edit, presumably because he thinks that the asker *should* be publicly shamed instead of just letting him learn.

On stack overflow (my main community) this sort of stuff would not stand - but I was wondering how this community dealt with it if at all.

Comment: Paricipate with our board for some time.  Post some answers.  Learn the customs.  Then see if you need to question them.

Comment: I wasn't questioning them in the sense of asking for change or anything - I was more just clarifying what they were.

Comment: On one hand the edit was approved, so I figure there has to be some people that agree that this paragraph was superfluous, but obviously the author did not...

Comment: Olin's remark is acceptable.  You editing it out was uncalled for.  You calling it "bitching" was uncalled for.

Comment: Fair call, the term "bitching" is considered profane by some. I've updated the title to use a less offensive word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. We are all volunteers here.  Asking a question about a unusual variant of something common, and not pointing that out is wasting time and is volunteer abuse.

   Either the OP hadn't thought about it, or was too absorbed in his own little problem to notice.  *Somebody* had to point it out to him.

   Telling someone how to ask a question properly, especially when they just did it wrong and caused wasted volunteer time (not just mine), is not berating them, bitching, or having a hissy fit (as you said in the edit comment).  Clearly they needed to hear it.

   Telling them publicly

   - Makes it impossible for them to claim later, in case of repeated occurance for example, that they didn't know.

     Has more impact since it's less easy to just skip over and not notice.

     Is hopefully something the offender finds at least a little uncomfortable, and is therefore much more likely to take care to avoid in the future.  Remember, their inconsiderate action was the original cause of all this, so making them squirm a bit is well deserved.

     Informs bystanders to head off them making the same mistake in the future.

   Part of the purpose was to inform readers why the answer apparently didn't match the question.  That answer got a few downvotes after the OP apparently provided more information in comments elsewhere.  Comments aren't for content, and we can't be expected to read them to answer questions.  We also aren't notified when a comment is added to a question we answered.  So unless we go back digging up old answers, then going to the top and reading the whole messy comment chain below the question, we don't know the OP said anything new.  Judging answers based on comments elsewhere, especially when posted after the answer, may be unfair, but it happens.

   Nothing in the statement you quote was personal or insulting.

   It is *You* who is out of line.  Your objection is that the original paragraph was only to berate the OP, however it was *you* who referred to others as "bitching" and having a "hissy fit".  I don't know of any universe where the second is acceptable but the first not.

Comment: Ok, if this is normal it's normal. Forgetting my comments, the only reason I edited it out was the stance on SO is that the question and answer should be written in such a way that it is helpful to other people coming along (ie, it's not just for the OP). That paragraph helps no-one except the OP. I'm accepting this as it seems pretty obvious from the comments here that people don't think that way here (which is fine of course).

Comment: Hi Olin, I'm one of the guys who accepted that edit.  I did it for the same reason that @shadow just explained: that any berating belongs (if anywhere) in the comments, not the answer.  Answers should be factual and helpful, not for commentary.  That being said, your answer to this Meta question is a good one.  Especially point #7 - there is irony that he was exhibiting the same behavior that he didn't approve of in your post. Thanks, Olin, for your incredible contributions to this site.

Comment: Yeah, I could have chosen my words more carefully. But there is a difference - what I wrote isn't in the answer. That doesn't fully absolve me or anything, but I think it's a difference worth mentioning.

Comment: @bitsmack berating doesn't belong anywhere!

Comment: @passerby Agreed, but I have to pick my battles :)

Comment: The truth of the matter is that Olin childishly blamed the asker for his own careless assumption that the mouse was USB, **despite the fact** that the schematic which formed the core of the original post is **obviously not that of a USB mouse**.  Further, the idea that non-USB mice are rare is false; especially in the realm of question here, the traditional synchronous serial variety have generally been preferred, since embedded USB hosts have only become inexpensive in the past few years.